# how to undo "stty intr ^M"

Tags: bash

On Unix bash, when I run `stty intr ^M` (^M is Control-M) I have effectively blocked myself from running any commands. Whenever I press the "return" key, I am sending the interrupt signal to the shell and my command is never run. Suppose I had this in my .profile (I don't actually..); how could I get myself out of this hole from a bash session with ^M set to trigger an interrupt signal?

Chris

Answer (score 3):

bash has both ^M and ^J bound to **`accept-line`** by default, so you can use either.

Comment: So `stty intr ^c^j` works.  You can also use `^v` to 'escape' the `^m`, so `stty intr ^c^v^j` works.  The only oddity there is that the `^j` and `^v` and `^m` have to be control-key codes; the `^c` can either be a control-key code or two characters, caret and v.

Answer (score 2):

In general (i.e. if things are even more messed up than this and you don't know how else to fix them), you can run `stty` from another tty using

```
stty sane < /dev/whatever
stty intr ^c < /dev/whatever
```

If you're not sure what tty has the messed up settings, use `who` or `ps` to find out what ttys you are using, and just `stty < /dev/whatever` each one in turn until you find the one that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest `stty sane ^J`, but that doesn't reset the interrupt. You'll have to do something like this:

```
$ stty intr ^C^J
```

The `^C` stands for the Control-C. You can usually get that by pressing Control-V/Control-C.